# Cell proliferation limit and senescence of embryonic stem cells and fibroblasts

Tags: cell-biology

I am trying to understand the importance of proliferation limits and cell senescence. In particular, I would like to compare the proliferation limit of Embryonic Stem cells (ES) and fibroblasts (which would be trans-differentiated) and describe how this difference plays a role when thinking about engineering organs, for example a heart transplant.

How do ES cells and fibroblasts compare with regards to the Hayflick limit?

Comment: You are right but this is  Not a homework question.

Comment: You may want to change the wording a bit, then as `compare the proliferation limit` and `describe how` makes it sound like it came from an assignment, it will probably get more attention :) I will delete my other comment then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telomeres (caps on the ends of chromosomes that are gradually shortened during each cell division) determine the maximum number of times a cell can divide, known as the 'Hayflick limit'. Cells that are able to express *telomerase*, an enzyme capable of extending the telomeres, can divide indefinitely.

There are various types of stem cell in a body which replenish the 'pool' of cells in the tissue once they reach the end of their useful lifespan. Each stem cell expresses telomerase to lengthen the telomeres after a round of cell division. The inhibition of telomerase in somatic (normal) cells is a major 'challenge' for cancerous cells - in order to achieve uninhibited proliferation, they must express telomerase. Thus, there are many molecular similarities between stem cells and cancerous cells (well, with regards to telomerase, anyway!) [[ref](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1218370)].

Fibroblasts are somatic cells - they are the 'normal' cells that make up the vast majority of organsisms. The only cells not known as somatic are gametes/germ cells and stem cells. They thus do not express telomerase, and have a *replicative lifespan*, also known as a Hayflick limit.

With regard to your question about engineering organs, there are many resident stem cells in tissues (and thus organs) that 'top-up' the somatic cells when required. As organisms age, this pool of stem cells becomes depleted [[ref](http://dx.doi.org/10.4161/cc.7.24.7214)]. Artificially engineering an organ such as the heart (I assume this is what you mean) would be inherently difficult, as many vascular cells are not replaced, but can last a whole lifetime - this is also true for many neuronal cells. So replicative lifespan is not necessarily related to lifespan!